# JSP pageContext properties

Tags: java, jsp, request, pagecontext

I'm trying a few examples from the O'Reilly Java Server Pages book by Hans Bergsten.

I'm stuck on the pageContext request properties! Not all of them are working. Most are ok, but these ones don't seem to work:

```
pageContext.request.contextPath
pageContext.request.servletPath
pageContext.request.requestURI
pageContext.request.requestURL
pageContext.request.cookies
```

I'm using jdk 8 in NetBeans.

Why doesnt it work?

Answer (score 0):

Arrrhh I see the problem now, it is working!

But netbeans autocomplete doesnt list those properties.